# PHP causing blank page - Updating user information

Tags: php

I have created a settings page to update user information. (I have successfully created a similar page to change the password and that worked fine.)

The following PHP script causes a blank page when the page is trying to load:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success']) === true) {
  echo 'Your details have been updated!';
} else {
 if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {

    $update_data = array(
        'info'      => $_POST['info'],
        'website'   => $_POST['website'],
        'location'  => $_POST['location'],
        'name'      => $_POST['name'],
        'email'     => $_POST['email'],

    update_user($session_user_id, $update_data);
    header('Location: settings.php?success');
      exit();

  } else if (empty($errors) === false) {
    echo output_errors($errors);
}
?>
```

Any ideas on what might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Blank page - 9 times out of 10 is because of a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @esqew said you did not close your array, But also you have not closed your first else statement.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['success'])) {
    echo 'Your details have been updated!';
}
else {
    if (!empty($_POST) && empty($errors)) {

        $update_data = array(
            'info'     => isset($_POST['info'])     ? $_POST['info']     : null,
            'website'  => isset($_POST['website'])  ? $_POST['website']  : null,
            'location' => isset($_POST['location']) ? $_POST['location'] : null,
            'name'     => isset($_POST['name'])     ? $_POST['name']     : null,
            'email'    => isset($_POST['email'])    ? $_POST['email']    : null,
        );

        update_user($session_user_id, $update_data);
        exit(header('Location: settings.php?success'));
    }

    if (!empty($errors)) {
        echo output_errors($errors);
    }
}
?>
```

As you can see, ive also changed your comparisons, there is **no need** to check the bool value of isset or empty, Just use `!` for not. Also check your $_POST values before using.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't close your `array` declaration:

```
$update_data = array(
    'info'      => $_POST['info'],
    'website'   => $_POST['website'],
    'location'  => $_POST['location'],
    'name'      => $_POST['name'],
    'email'     => $_POST['email'],
```

should be

```
$update_data = array(
    'info'      => $_POST['info'],
    'website'   => $_POST['website'],
    'location'  => $_POST['location'],
    'name'      => $_POST['name'],
    'email'     => $_POST['email']
);
```

---

While outside the scope of your question, it is good to mention if you're getting blank pages with code like this, you may want to inspect your error reporting levels. PHP throws pretty descriptive errors when configured correctly. For more information, you might want to take a look at [`error_reporting()` entry in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

Comment: Might be worth mentioning error reporting

Comment: @user574632 Absolutely agreed - edited.